# iPhone Digital Clock

Tags: ios, timer, nsstring, clock, digital

After the long time I spent getting an analog clock to work, I am trying to make a digital one (*sigh*).  I am trying to do this with 10 PNGs with the numbers 0 - 9.  Each digit of the clock would be an image.  The only problem with this is retrieving the certain digit from the current time.  I've tried converting the time to a string and using the characterAtIndex, but that doesn't seem to work.  What would be the best way to get around this?

Comment: Hi @Andy have u r problem solved because i have the same problem as urs .Please can u help me in making a digital with 10 images (0-9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents * components =
                    [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

NSInteger hour = [weekdayComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [weekdayComponents minute];
NSInteger firstHourDigit = hour/10;
NSInteger secondHourDigit = hour%10;
NSInteger firstMinuteDigit = minute/10;
NSInteger secondMinuteDigit = minute%10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is an interesting approach.  I didn't think it would be this easy! I'll try it out soon.

Comment: This doesn't work though... I tried using this:         [minOne setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", secondMinuteDigit]]];  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't update the image even though I'm using an nstimer... The image does show up, however.