# Get Date and Time in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, time, clock

I'd like to have three labels in my application, the first shows the time, the second shows the day and the third shows the month. Now I know how to get the current date with NSDate and date formats and all, but how can I update the day when another day begins? And the same with months? And NSDate shows what time it is, but I'm looking to do a digital clock, how would I go on about that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really broad and questions like this have been asked on S.O. many times.

like here -> [how to create a digital clock with custom images for hours and seconds in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631709/how-to-create-a-digital-clock-with-custom-images-for-hours-and-seconds-in-iphone)

and here -> [iPhone Digital Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881992/iphone-digital-clock)

Here is a tutorial on how to create an analog clock for iOS -> http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/03/analog-clock-using-quartz-core.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if your system follow **POSIX** standards, but if it does you might consider using the *gettimeofday* system call and the *localtime* and *strftime* standard library functions. They have C APIs and should be callable by Objective-C code, and very probably you might have higher level library calls.